# Select Inner JSON fields with TypeORM

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeorm

I have a table in my PostgreSQL database, This table has a json field named *data* and in this data column I have stored something like this:

```
{"info":{"title":"test"}}
```

How can I select just the *title* from this column with TypeORM. I used the code below but I get an error:

```
return await this.myRepository.findAndCount({
      select:['data -> "info" -> "tile" AS title']
      take: 10,
      skip: 10,
    });
```